# answer set programming "Guesses"

Tags: answer-set-programming, clingo

I want to pick exactly "steps" item from the guess block however I got unsat when I limit the guess with cardinalities.

```
  % Pick a series of move
  %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
  steps { 
          vpr(X,Y) : verticalPlus(X,Y); 
          vmr(X,Y) : verticalMinus(X,Y); 
          hpr(X,Y) : horizontalPlus(X,Y); 
          hmr(X,Y) : horizontalMinus(X,Y) 
 } steps.
```

Comment: there are more choices than "steps".

Comment: This seems like a bug, when I change "steps" which is a constant with 3,4,5 etc... it works.

Comment: Please provide a minimal example that shows what's failing.  Can you give values/instantiations for steps, verticalPlus, verticalMinus, horizontalPlus, and horizontalMinus?